# circles with equal radius and at a distance from each other.

Tags: geometry

In the attached image, 
[image: Circles]

A and B are centres of two congruent circles. C is the midpoint of AB. How do I prove that chord DG = chord EF?
I've tried a lot,but could only prove DC = CE.
(I am a high school student, so I would appreciate if you could give me a simple proof.)

Comment: Did you mean $DC=EC$? How did you prove that? I suspect you are almost to the result you want.

Comment: Edited the question.Sorry.

Comment: Draw the segments from A to D and G, and from B to F and G. (oops. ignore this; I can't seem to delete it).

Comment: Note the opposite angles at C are congruent, draw some radii in the circles, and use congruent triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label the place where $CA$ hits circle $A$ $H$ and where $CB$ hits circle $B$ $J$. Extend the segments $CA$ and $CB$ until they hit their respective circles again and label those points $I$ and $K$, respectively. Apply the [Secant Secant Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Secant_Secant_Theorem) which is also called the [Intersecting Secants Theorem](http://www.mathopenref.com/secantsintersecting.html).

So you get that $CH \cdot CI = CG \cdot CD$ and $CJ \cdot CK = CF \cdot CE$. But you have proven that $CD = CE$ and by construction of $C$ as the midpoint of $AB$ we must have that $CH = CJ$ and $CI = CK$. Thus, $CG = CF$.

Finally we have $DG = CD - CG = CE - CF = EF$.

Answer (score 0):

Using your result DC = CE, we have congruent triangles DCA and ECB by Side-angle-side postulate. Draw from A a perpendicular to DG (call this point X) and from B draw a perpendicular to FE (call this point Y) Then DG and FE are bisected. So by HL theorem, triangles AXC and BYC are congruent. and so XG = YF from here it follows DG = EF